# Using python to achieve replace function

Tags: python, input, readfile, writefile

I am trying to operate some file like this:

```
*sline
1, 1.0, 2.23
2, 1.0, 9.98
3, 2.0, 10.00
*eline
```

Now I have a list, which contain data like this:

```
datalist = [[1,1.0,2.0],[3,2.0,2.0]]
```

I want to put the value which belong to datalist to replace the value in the file by id(datalist[][0]), like:

```
*sline
1, 1.0, 2.0
2, 1.0, 9.98
3, 2.0, 2.0
*eline
```

I am try to utilse:

```
o = open("file","a") 
for line in open("trychange.txt"):
   line = line.replace("1, 1.0, 2.23","1, 1.0, 2.0")
   line = line.replace("3, 2.0, 10.00","3, 2.0, 2.0")
   o.write(line + "\n") 
o.close()
```

but it doesn't work, it just add new values but didn't change the old one.
how can I deal with this?
Thanks for your helping

Comment: There's probably a better way to try to do what you're describing than the hard coded replaces you're doing, but I suspect the adding new values problem is because you're opening `file` with the `a` flag to open it in append mode, so every time you run it you'll be adding all the output again

Comment: Use `o = open("file","w") ` instead of `o = open("file","a") ` as `a` appends to the previous value and does not erase the original contents